# How to select a level and all sub levels(and items) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multilevel `dataframe`:

```
year month  Open      High      Low       Close
2018 1      25565.75  27379.45  27652.05  25232.80
     2      27334.85  25107.40  27613.50  24781.70
     3      25022.35  24263.35  25226.05  23605.60
     4      24235.65  25531.60  25617.50  24062.95
     5      25607.05  26956.20  27164.55  25469.05
2019 1      27231.40  27720.40  27754.45  26923.75
```

I am trying to get the `2018` `type (int64)` selected and made into a separate dataframe.

I have tried:

`df[2017]`

I get a `key error`

`df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[0,'Open']]`

This gets me all Open prices.

`df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['year':,'Open']]`

`df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['2017','Open']]`

They don't seem to work.

How to access the levels? Keeping in mind they are int64 type?

Output expected:

```
     month  Open      High      Low       Close
     1      25565.75  27379.45  27652.05  25232.80
     2      27334.85  25107.40  27613.50  24781.70
     3      25022.35  24263.35  25226.05  23605.60
     4      24235.65  25531.60  25617.50  24062.95
     5      25607.05  26956.20  27164.55  25469.05
```

Also if there was another level how would I go about accessing two levels down data?

Thanks

Comment: Please cross check you are trying to access 2017 instead of 2018.

Comment: Thanks @Lalit the datframe is larger and 2018 is also in the index. I made a typo. Here but strangely now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want seelct index, so need `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[2018]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = df.xs(2018)
```

Or if want select all values in second level need `:` :

```
df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[2018,:]]
print (df)
           Open      High       Low     Close
month                                        
1      25565.75  27379.45  27652.05  25232.80
2      27334.85  25107.40  27613.50  24781.70
3      25022.35  24263.35  25226.05  23605.60
4      24235.65  25531.60  25617.50  24062.95
5      25607.05  26956.20  27164.55  25469.05
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `iloc` with `get_level_values`:

```
2018_df = df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('year') == 2018].reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

       Open        High       Low        Close
month               
1   25565.75    27379.45    27652.05    25232.80
2   27334.85    25107.40    27613.50    24781.70
3   25022.35    24263.35    25226.05    23605.60
4   24235.65    25531.60    25617.50    24062.95
5   25607.05    26956.20    27164.55    25469.05
```

or if you want to access another level:

```
month_1_df = df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('month') == 1].reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

           Open        High         Low        Close
year                
2018    25565.75    27379.45    27652.05    25232.80
2019    27231.40    27720.40    27754.45    26923.75
```

or to access more than one level use `transpose`:

```
df.T.loc[:, (2018, 3)].to_frame().T

             Open         High        Low        Close
2018    3   25022.35    24263.35    25226.05    23605.6
```

now you can select any column(s) you want: `df.T.loc[:, (2018, 3)].to_frame().T[['Open', 'Close']]`